# Why does ps -ax list itself?

Tags: ps

How does

```
ps -ax
```

list itself as a running process?

Testing methodology:

```
ps -ax | grep "ps \-ax"
```

also, the `PID` is different each time, so I know that it isn't just running in another `TTY` or something.

Comment: Because it is a process at the time you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `ps -ax` will list itself, because `ps -ax` is a running process!

In fact you're typing your command in the shell, and the shell will create the new process for you. `ps -ax` see itself because it exists while it's running...

The next time you call it, it will have a new PID since you run it once more.